# Is there a way combine posts meta_name?

Tags: post-meta

I want to know if there is a way that 2 different custom fields that have basicly the same value function to be combined.

1) meta_name: my_link and meta_value: a link
2) meta_name: other_link and meta_value: other link

It should work like this:
The general call in my template is

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_link', true) ) : ?>

<?php echo $my_link; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

So if in the post is present meta_name: other_link and not my_link and in the template is queried my_link, I want the other_link meta_name to be recognized as meta_name: my_link.

I searched all over.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the same meta_key for multiple values, for example:

**meta_key** - 'links' **meta_value** - 'link1'

**meta_key** - 'links' **meta_value** - 'link2'

then you can get the meta as an array of links:

```
$links = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'links');
if ($links){
    foreach ($links as $link){
        echo $link;
    }
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for the answer, I know that but the I can not control the custom fields,  I only control the query from the theme for the custom field (I know I can make all the same meta_key from database, but as I said I can do that because I control only the theme) the custom fields are are created by two plugins and I want the theme to be compatible with both meta_keys.

Comment: I see what you mean, then i guess you can always add an `elseif` before your `end if`, let me know if thats ok

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you retrieve both values and then decide which to use? As (messy) one liner it can be expressed like this:

```
if(
    ( $my_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_link', true) )
    ||
    ( $my_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'other_link', true) )
    )
    echo $my_link;
```